# Importing an exported pool on Solaris 11 fails

Tags: solaris, zfs, import, zpool, solaris-11

Unable to import an exported pool.

Based on the info below, am I able to somehow import the pool? Or, is there a way to retrieve the data from the drive itself?

There is no corruption on either disks.

Solaris 11.3

```
# zpool upgrade -v
This system is currently running ZFS pool version 37.

# zpool import
no pools available to import
```

I've tried the various flags: `-a`, `-d`, `-f`... but still cannot import the pool.

If I run `# zdb -l /dev/dsk/c2d1` it outputs...

```
failed to read label 0
failed to read label 1
failed to read label 2
failed to read label 3  
------------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------------
timestamp: 1473551773 date = Sat Sep 10 19:56:13 EDT 2016
version: 37
name: 'media_pool'
state: 1
txg: 2897535
pool_guid: 5338829418358414155
hostid: 4878442
hostname: 'solaris'
top_guid: 9706852805983701681
guid: 18084312246070035927
vdev_children: 1
vdev_tree:
    type: 'mirror'
    id: 0
    guid: 9706852805983701681
    metaslab_array: 27
    metaslab_shift: 33
    ashift: 9
    asize: 1494648619008
    is_log: 0
    create_txg: 4
    children[0]:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 0
        guid: 18084312246070035927
        path: '/dev/dsk/c2d1s0'
        devid: 'id1,cmdk@AWDC_WD1502FAEX-007BA0=_____WD-xxxxxxxxxxxx/a'
        phys_path: '/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:a'
        whole_disk: 1
        DTL: 101
        create_txg: 4
    children[1]:
        type: 'disk'
        id: 1
        guid: 14097338398603359817
        path: '/dev/dsk/c5d0s0'
        devid: 'id1,cmdk@AWDC_WD1502FAEX-007BA0=_____WD-xxxxxxxxxxxx/a'
        phys_path: '/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,5/ide@1/cmdk@0,0:a'
        whole_disk: 1
        DTL: 100
        create_txg: 4
------------------------------------------
LABEL 1 - CONFIG MATCHES LABEL 0
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
LABEL 2 - CONFIG MATCHES LABEL 0
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
LABEL 3 - CONFIG MATCHES LABEL 0
------------------------------------------
```

---

additional information

```
# ls -l /dev/dsk/c2d1*  
52 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:wd
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1p0 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:q
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1p1 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:r
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1p2 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:s
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1p3 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:t
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1p4 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:u
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s0 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:a
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s1 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:b
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s10 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:k
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s11 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:l
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s12 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:m
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s13 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:n
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s14 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:o
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s15 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:p
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s2 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:c
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s3 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:d
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s4 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:e
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s5 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:f
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s6 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:g
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s8 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:i
51 Mar  7  2016 /dev/dsk/c2d1s9 -> ../../devices/pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0:j
```

also, might be useful, please note I've physically disconnected the 2nd mirror drive from media_pool. (importing didn't work with both drives on a Live CD or the original install).

```
# format
Searching for disks...done
AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c2d1 <WDC WD15-  WD-xxxxxxxxxxx-0001-1.36TB>
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@0/cmdk@1,0
       1. c3d0 <WDC WD10-  WD-xxxxxxxxxxx-0001-931.51GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@1/cmdk@0,0
       2. c3d1 <WDC WD10-  WD-xxxxxxxxxxx-0001-931.51GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci-ide@1f,2/ide@1/cmdk@1,0
```

rpool is where solaris resides.

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC  FREE  CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool  928G  28.3G  900G   3%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Comment: Just in case: is the pool imported already? Anyway, please show the output of `ls -l /dev/dsk/c2d1*`

Comment: @TomShaw No, when I try to `zpool import` it outputs `no pools available to import`. I have a feeling it's something to do with the disk labels...

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is a workaround. The correct answer should address why `zpool import` isn't correctly importing the pool despite zbd picking up LABEL 0 but not 'reading' it correctly.

---

All was not lost. Take one of the mirrored drives and stick it on another machine, boot from a Solaris 11.3 LiveCD (or at least a version of the OS that's got a similar zfs version).

`zpool import media_pool` was successful on a different box. Now export it.
`zpool export media_pool`

On the original machine clear the /etc/zfs/zpool.cache. Poweroff. Remove the second mirrored drive. Insert original mirrored drive (the one exported from the step above on a different box). Reboot the machine and import the pool.

Comment: That's a weird one! You said a Live CD on the same machine didn't work. Different Live CD?

Comment: @TomShaw it was the same bootable USB (aka Live CD) but ran it on a different box. You are correct in the sense that a Live CD should have worked on the original box if there was only that one drive. The only delta here was the box, the physical USB and hdd was same.

Comment: Maybe a zpool import bug which is worked around with a different device path. If it happens again it would be interesting to see if moving the disk around in the same machine helps.